# Converting list into string while keeping it word by word

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Frustrated to say I'm stumped on this one. I'm extracting text from a paragraph:

```
    paragraphs = re.findall(r'(<p(.*?)</p>)', html)
```

Then I want to scrap the tags and just keep the paragraph text, word by word:

```
    paragraphs = re.sub(r'\<.*?\>', '', paragraphs)
```

Problem is that Python expects a string. If I understand it right I have to turn "paragraphs" into a string first. But, when I do:

```
    paragraphs = str(paragraphs)
```

…I get the text letter by letter, the words are broken apart. Well, I'm new to Python and this confuses me.

1st question: Why isn't "paragraphs" a string to begin with?

2nd question: How do I convert "paragraph" into a string, keeping it word by word, such as:

```
    paragraph = ['Two', 'words']
```

Answer (score 2):

`re.findall()` returns a *list* of matches. You need `re.search()` instead.

A better option though would be to use an *HTML Parser*, like [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> 
>>> data = '<p>some text here</p>'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
>>> soup.p.get_text().split()
[u'some', u'text', u'here']
```